# nginx 502 Bad Gateway error. How large should my buffer be?

Tags: php, xml, nginx, error-handling

I have a Nginx server which sole purpose is to read XML and to put it in a database.

If the files are small, let's say 100MB everything works well. But If Im trying to `SimpleXMLELement` a file of around 700MB I get a 502 Bad Gateway warning.

I read up on the problem and fiddled with the settings below, but it didnt help yet. Should my buffers be larger? As in: 700M or something?

nginx.conf (in http{}):

```
fastcgi_buffers 128 128k;
fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
fastcgi_connect_timeout 3000;
fastcgi_send_timeout 3000;
fastcgi_read_timeout 3000;
```

I have `ini_set("memory_limit", "-1");` in my php script and `php_admin_value[memory_limit] = 2042M` in php-fpm.conf

```
[03-Jul-2015 11:53:44] WARNING: [pool www] child 6327 exited on signal 9 (SIGKILL) after 19.047513 seconds from start
[03-Jul-2015 12:16:12] WARNING: [pool www] child 6518 exited on signal 9 (SIGKILL) after 23.669892 seconds from start
[03-Jul-2015 12:22:13] NOTICE: configuration file /opt/nginxstack-1.8.0-0/php/etc/php-fpm.conf test is successful

[03-Jul-2015 12:23:35] WARNING: [pool www] child 7089 exited on signal 9 (SIGKILL) after 23.245077 seconds from start
```

(After changes I restart the server).

Comment: Your application is likely throwing an exception  somewhere. The 502 is just what nginx ends up displaying. You need to track down your actual application errors.

Comment: it's nothing to do with nginx. Fix your applicaton, it's probably crashing with out of memory error.

Comment: `error.log` shows recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream. Hmm I'll check this out..

Comment: @AlexeyTen I fiddled with that already too, I have `ini_set("memory_limit", "-1");` in my php script and `php_admin_value[memory_limit] = 2042M` in php-fpm.conf. And restarted. Problem persists...

Comment: And do you have php log?

Comment: @AlexeyTen Ill add it to the post...

Comment: Well, as I said, your PHP worker crashed. Fix it

Comment: @AlexeyTen Ok, could you point me in the right direction maybe? I kinda figured there was something wrong, hence the post, but where do I start?

Comment: I guess `SimpleXMLELement` could not handle large XML's, so you should use something else. Better choice would be some streaming parser or else you'll end up with the same problem but on bigger file.

Comment: Okidoki, Ill skip the memory hog and write myself a generator! Thanks Alexey!

Comment: this must not be a PHP problem. you should better analyse the error conditions and add up. you should also check PHP error logs (if you haven't logging enabled for PHP, enable it then). don't rewrite parts of your code unless you know what actually the concern is about. also you don't show any code in the question so it's really hard to tell what the issue might be. For streaming read of XML, PHP has **XMLReader** - but check what the concrete issue is first.